# Exception thrown on trying to instantiate http_client

Tags: c++, exception, httpclient, cpprest-sdk

I'm trying to run a simple example with http_client, using CppRestSDK 2.10 (Casablanca) but on trying to create the http_client instance, it crashes with the exception in the attached image.

The line of code that triggers the exception is -

*http_client client(U("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos"));*

That's the first line in main()

CppRestSDK was installed using *vcpkg install cpprestsdk:x64-windows*

Please help...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

OK, found it, I apparently was trying to link release lib to my debug build.

Thanks go to https://github.com/Microsoft/cpprestsdk/issues/694